# How to make 2 objects appearing as connected (while remaining separated in the outliner)

Tags: modeling

Newbie here, can find an answer for this even though there must be already somewhere.
My doubt:
2 separate objects need to look like connected (for instance: a pole and a concrete block).
Instead of messing around with the snap feature, or creating vertex using weight to apply the shrinkwrap mod on the target object (the concrete block lets say), is there a reason NOT to just insert (moving) the pole edge inside the concrete block (taking care for it not to emerge on the other side) and just leave it there as it is?
Is this way of doing considered kind of not the proper one?
Thank you!

Comment: Sure you can :) Its always about your needs and expectations.

Comment: ... in fact, it's a general rule. Model separate parts as separate parts. (Maybe not always separate objects) . Blender is an animation and visualisation application.It's about what things _look_ like, not what they are.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I know of NOT to intermesh objects would be that it may cause complications with modifiers (eg. subsurface modifier).  But for all the hard surface stuff I do, my gosh, 99% of it is objects overlapping eachother. Another solution is the boolean tool. It can union/join objects together so there's no inner/hidden vertecies.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense!